# Android convert Transparent color to drawable

Tags: android

Is there a way how can I set the `buttonDrawable` of a `CheckBox` to transparent ?

Setting it like this: `setButtonDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);` doesn't work. I don't remember if there was a solution converting a color as a `Drawable` and use it like this for example. What I've searched so far and I saw it worked is to set the Transparent Color from `XML` but I don't have one and I would like to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can give `new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)` a try

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for, you don't know how much blank space did I have that I couldn't remember this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked:

```
new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00ffffff"));
```